How to lattitude, longtitude and full address based on address?
I have a dataframe with column address_1:
address_1
apple fifth avenue new york
burj khalifa dubai
microsoft office san francisco

I want to get longtitude, lattitude and full address based on address_1. How to di it? I tried geopandas library:
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
location = geolocator.geocode("apple fifth avenue new york")
address = location.address
latitude = location.latitude
longitude = location.longitude
print(latitude, longitude)

but i get this error:
GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py in _adapter_error_handler(self, error)
    409                 ) from error
    410             else:
--> 411                 raise exc_cls(str(error)) from error
    412         else:
    413             res = self._geocoder_exception_handler(error)

GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: Non-successful status code 403


That's because you need to specify a user-agent that is not a sample nor a default (read more).
Also, since you're dealing with what looks like a pandas' DataFrame and you tagged geopandas, you can simply geocode each address, then get_coordinates :
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.tools.geocode(df["address_1"], provider="arcgis", user_agent="foo")

gdf = gdf.join(gdf.get_coordinates().set_axis(["lon", "lat"], axis=1))

NB: I'm using "ArcGis" as a provider because "Nominatim" fails to recognise  the 3rd address.
                      geometry              address         lon        lat
0   POINT (-73.97267 40.76371)   Apple Fifth Avenue  -73.972672  40.763715
1    POINT (55.27594 25.18961)  Burj Khalifa, Dubai   55.275938  25.189615
2  POINT (-122.40410 37.79221)     Microsoft Office -122.404096  37.792208


Used input :
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "address_1": [
            "apple fifth avenue new york",
            "burj khalifa dubai",
            "microsoft office san francisco",
        ]
    }
)

